# Multer file upload not working multipart/form-data image

Tags: vue.js, file-upload, axios, multipartform-data, multer

I am using nuxt.js. I used a package [vue-picture-input](https://github.com/alessiomaffeis/vue-picture-input) and am using [this](https://alligator.io/vuejs/uploading-vue-picture-input/) tutorial to upload the image file. To upload it to the server using axios on my api:

```
export default function (url, file, name = 'avatar') {
  if (typeof url !== 'string') {
    throw new TypeError(`Expected a string, got ${typeof url}`);
  }

  // You can add checks to ensure the url is valid, if you wish

  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append(name, file);
  const config = {
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }
  };

  return axios.post(url, formData, config);
};
```

I double checked before sending, the formData indeed has the image. This request then goes to the backend and received by the following code:

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: 'some-destination',
    filename: function (req, file, callback) {
        crypto.pseudoRandomBytes(16, function(err, raw) {
            if (err) return callback(err);
          
            callback(null, raw.toString('hex') + path.extname(file.originalname));
        });
    }
});

var upload = multer({ storage : storage})

router.post('/upload/add', upload.single('avatar'), (req, res) => {
    if (!req.file) {
        console.log("No file received");
        return res.send({
          success: false
        });
    
    } else {
        console.log('file received');
        return res.send({
          success: true
        })
    }

    // Everything went fine 
})
```

I know I am doing this in a weird way - using formData instead of actually submitting an html form..but in my scenario its better. Whenever I run this code, the response is always `success: false`.
Does that mean it can't find the formData image? I would really appreciate it if you could help me debug this. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While researching a similar problem I came across this post. I have this working in a similar way. It might help to remove the content-type header, it is set by axios/formdata automatically for me. It should include a boundary generated by formdata like this.

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary5g0xJihuBbfw8DEp
```